# Connect-N Board Game, crashing when Width is >> Height

Tags: c, cygwin

I'm in the process of coding a Connect-N board game, and I'm almost finished and have gone through troubleshooting. My problem is now after changing some stuff my game crashes when the computer plays its move if the Width is too much greater than the height. There are two functions involved here, so I will paste them both.

```
Board
*AllocateBoard(int columns, int rows)
        {
        int **array= malloc(sizeof(int *) *columns);
        int r = 0;
        for ( r = 0; r < columns; ++r)
                {
                array[r] = malloc(sizeof(int) * rows);
                }
        int j = columns - 1;
        int k = rows - 1;
        int m = 0;
        int n = 0;
        for ( m = 0; m < j; ++m)
                {
                for ( n = 0; n < k; ++n)
                        {
                        array[m][n] = 0;
                        }
                }
        Board *board = malloc(sizeof(Board));
        board->columns = columns;
        board->rows = rows;
        board->spaces = array;
        return board;
        }
```

This first function allocates the board to be a matrix Width * Height that the user passes in via the command line. It then initializes every space on the board to be zero, and then stores the columns, rows, and spaces into a Board structure that I've created. It then returns the board.

```
int
computerMakeMove(Board *board)
{       int RandIndex = 0;
        int **spaces = board->spaces;
        int columns = board->columns;
        int *arrayoflegalmoves = malloc(sizeof(int) * (columns));
        int columncheck = 0;
        int legalmoveindex = 0;
        while (columncheck <= columns - 1)
        {
                if (spaces[columncheck][0] == 0)
                        {
                        arrayoflegalmoves[legalmoveindex] = columncheck;
                        ++legalmoveindex;
                        ++columncheck;
                        }
                else
                        {
                        ++columncheck;
                        }
                arrayoflegalmoves = realloc(arrayoflegalmoves, (legalmoveindex) * sizeof(int));
        }
        if (legalmoveindex == 1)
        {
                return arrayoflegalmoves[0];
        }
        else
        {
                RandIndex = rand() % (legalmoveindex);
                return arrayoflegalmoves[RandIndex];
        }
}
```

This second function is designed to make the computer randomly pick a column on the board. It does this by checking the value of the top row in each column. If there is a zero there, it will store this value in an array of legal moves, and then it increments the legalmoveindex. If there isn't, it skips the column and checks the next. It ends when it gets finished checking the final column. If there is only one legal move, it will play it. If there are more, it will select a random index from the array of legal moves (I run srand in the main) and then return that value. It will only ever attempt to play on a legal board, so that's not the problem. I am pretty confident the problem occurs in this function, however, as I call the functions as follows

```
  printf("Taking the computers move.\n");
        {printf("Taking computer's move.");
         computermove = computerMakeMove(playerboard);
         printf("Computer's move successfully taken.\n");
         playerboard = MakeMove(playerboard, computermove, player);
         printf("Computer's board piece successfully played.\n");
         system("clear");
         displayBoard(playerboard);
         ...;
        }
```

and it prints

```
Aborted (core dumped)
```

immediately after it prints

```
"Taking computer's move."
```

Once again, my question is: why is my program crashing if the width is larger than the height when the computer plays?

Thanks.

Edit: I found the solution and I am stupid.

I realloc'd during the while loop.
The realloc should be the first thing outside of the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for any future programmers who may have this problem:

Notice the

```
while (columncheck <= columns - 1)
        {
                if (spaces[columncheck][0] == 0)
                        {
                        arrayoflegalmoves[legalmoveindex] = columncheck;
                        ++legalmoveindex;
                        ++columncheck;
                        }
                else
                        {
                        ++columncheck;
                        }
                arrayoflegalmoves = realloc(arrayoflegalmoves, (legalmoveindex) * sizeof(int));
        }
```

has a realloc inside of it. The realloc should be moved to immediately outside of it, like so

```
while (columncheck <= columns - 1)
        {
                if (spaces[columncheck][0] == 0)
                        {
                        arrayoflegalmoves[legalmoveindex] = columncheck;
                        ++legalmoveindex;
                        ++columncheck;
                        }
                else
                        {
                        ++columncheck;
                        }
        }
        arrayoflegalmoves = realloc(arrayoflegalmoves, (legalmoveindex) * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
it is unusual to have the columns be the first index in an array.
having the first index of an array be columns leads to confusion


// suggest using camel case for all variable names, for readability

Board *AllocateBoard(int columns, int rows)
{
    int **array= malloc(sizeof(int *) *columns); // add check that malloc successful
    int r = 0;

    for ( r = 0; r < columns; ++r)
    {
        array[r] = malloc(sizeof(int) * rows); // <-- add: check that malloc successful
    }

    int j = columns - 1; // this results in last column not initialized
    int k = rows - 1;    // this results in last row of each column not initialized
    int m = 0; // column loop counter
    int n = 0; // row loop counter

    for ( m = 0; m < j; ++m)
    {
        for ( n = 0; n < k; ++n)
        {
                array[m][n] = 0;
        }
    }

    Board *board = malloc(sizeof(Board)); // <-- add: check if malloc successful
    board->columns = columns;
    board->rows = rows;
    board->spaces = array;
    return board;
} // end function: AllocateBoard


// why is this only looking at the first row of each column?
int computerMakeMove(Board *board)
{
    int RandIndex = 0;
    int **spaces = board->spaces;
    int columns = board->columns;
    int *arrayoflegalmoves = malloc(sizeof(int) * (columns)); // <-- add check that malloc successful
    int columncheck = 0;
    int legalmoveindex = 0;

    while (columncheck <= columns - 1)// should be: for(; columncheck < columns; columncheck++ )
    {
        if (spaces[columncheck][0] == 0)
        { // then first row of column is zero
            arrayoflegalmoves[legalmoveindex] = columncheck;
            ++legalmoveindex;
            ++columncheck; // <-- remove this line
        }

        else // remove this 'else' code block
        {
            ++columncheck;
        } // end if

        arrayoflegalmoves = realloc(arrayoflegalmoves, (legalmoveindex) * sizeof(int));
        // <-- 1) use temp int*, in case realloc fails
        // <-- 2) if realloc successful, update arrayoflegalmoves
        // <-- 3) the code is not checking each row of each column,
        //        so the original malloc is more than plenty
        //        so why bother to realloc
        // <-- 4) if legalmoveindex is 0 then realloc returns NULL
    } // end while

    // in following, what about when zero moves found? probably should return NULL
    if (legalmoveindex == 1)
    { // only one column[row0] found to contain 0
        return arrayoflegalmoves[0];
    }

    else
    {
        RandIndex = rand() % (legalmoveindex);
        return arrayoflegalmoves[RandIndex]; // if zero moves found, this returns a
                                             // de-reference to address 0
                                             // which would result in a seg fault event
    } // end if
} // end function: computerMakeMove
```